# Finding the sum of numbers input to a file

Tags: python

I'm having an issue finding the sum of a string of numbers. I should be able to enter 1234 and receive the answer of 10. When I run the code, it just outputs what I put in, rather than giving me the sum of the numbers.

```
##This program will allow a user to insert random numbers into the program, and calculate     the sum of those numbers

#Get Input Numbers
inputNumbers = input("Please input the numbers you would like to add here: ")

#Write the numbers to a file
file = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
file.write(str(inputNumbers))
file.close()

#Read the numbers from the file and calculate the sum
file.read(str("numbers.txt"))
theSum = 0
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    number = int(line)
    theSum += number
print("The sum is", theSum)
```

Comment: Can you describe what `for line in file` does? What is `line` in each iteration of that loop? Knowing this `line`, what is `number`? What happens to `theSum` when you add this `number` to it? Why do you expect it to add the _digits_ of the number? See [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
and
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: What's the purpose of writing a file if you're just reading it back? (the file isn't the problem)

Comment: Hint: `print(number)` before adding to the sum and you'll see why it's adding "what you typed"

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse each character in the line

```
theSum += sum(int(c) for c in line)
```

Or skip the file entirely, and do the same with `inputNumbers`

Answer (score 0):

If your using string to int conversion it will convert "1234" to 1234. If you want to get digit sum, you will need to iterate over every char in the string and convert them individually to integers. When I replaced the 'file' with 'inputNumbers' in the for loop it worked for me.